# Image on gallery dissapear when exiting the modal that shows that specific image

Tags: javascript, html, css

i created a dom event that when i click a specific button it will show me the specific image related to that button but when i close the modal the image gets taken in the modal section and dissapears from the page. how to prevent this from happening?

[`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/a05pj7w1/8/)

Comment: your image is inside a div with `Id="modalGallery"`, and youre setting `galleryModal.style.display='none';`  which hides everything that is in the div with that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a little bit of your buttonsGallery.forEach code add this in your example and see

```
       buttonsGallery.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                galleryModal.style.display = 'flex';
                // creating element img
                let modalIMG = document.createElement('img')
                // adding src to it's
                modalIMG.src = btn.nextElementSibling.src;
                //   remove first child if there is any inside modalContent
                modalContent.innerHTML = ""
                // adding current child
                modalContent.appendChild(modalIMG);
                modalContent.firstElementChild.className = 'modalImgTaken';
                modalContent.firstElementChild.style.width = '100%';
                modalContent.firstElementChild.style.height = '100%';
                modalContent.firstElementChild.style.objectFit = 'contain';
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep at maximum code you have done, but with "mandatory" changes only...

First don't use id several times, very bad idea.

Second the src is the next sibling src not the next sibling.

Second when you create your modalIMG, you append it, and you still have the element modalIMG to add style, class... whatever, no need to search first element child...

```js
const galleryModal = document.querySelector('#modalGallery');
const modalContent = document.querySelector('.modal-content');
const buttonsGallery = document.querySelectorAll('button.modalGalleryBtn');
const mainGallery = document.querySelectorAll('.containerGallery');



buttonsGallery.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    galleryModal.style.display = 'flex';
    const modalIMG = document.createElement('img');
    modalContent.innerHTML = '';
    modalContent.appendChild(modalIMG);
    modalIMG.src = btn.nextElementSibling.src;
    modalIMG.classList.add('modalImgTaken');
    modalIMG.style.width = '100%';
    modalIMG.style.height = '100%';
    modalIMG.style.objectFit = 'contain';
  })
})


const modalGalleryClose = document.querySelector('#closeGalleryModal');
modalGalleryClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
  galleryModal.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Junge&family=Montserrat:wght@300&family=Quicksand&family=Rubik+Mono+One&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #360882;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10vh;
  margin-top: 8vh;
}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background: none;
}

.gallery-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  filter: drop-shadow(20px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-container button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 19.5vh;
  bottom: -2vh;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ac3925;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-shadow: 20px 15px 10px #00000086;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.gallery-container button:hover {
  background: #DC2B0B;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.712);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(6vh);
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.modalCloseBtn {
  transform: translate(132vh, -32vh);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modalCloseBtn img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-container containerGallery">
    <button class="modalGalleryBtn">See Image</button>
    <img src=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1674821503660-9445aab3d662?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80 alt="01">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-container containerGallery">
    <button class="modalGalleryBtn">See Image</button>
    <img src=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1674718061623-2d1902f6889d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80 alt="02">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-container containerGallery">
    <button class="modalGalleryBtn">See Image</button>
    <img src=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1674763973434-75e1930d4959?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80 alt="03">
  </div>
</section>
<div class="modal" id="modalGallery">
  <div class="modalCloseBtn" id="closeGalleryModal">
    <img src=https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-close-512.png>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content" id="modal-contentGallery"></div>
</div>
```